# MVC 4 Razor If splitting div tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following MVC 4 Razor code:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

    if (currentCol == 1) {
        Html.Raw("<div class=row>");
    @*Need to do this because can't have a open div within a if compiler doesnt like it *@
    } if (currentCol == maxCol) {
        Html.Raw("</div>");
    }
    currentCol++;
}
```

I am basically trying to generate the contents of every div class row conditionally with the start and end tags in different paths of the if statements. When I just use straight HTML, the compiler doesn't like it and thinks the brackets are off. It seems like `Html.Raw` is the solution from my searches online, but when I use `Html.Raw`, the div doesn't show up when I view the source.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try prefixing the `Html.Raw` calls with `@`:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
{
    if (currentCol == 1) 
    {
        @Html.Raw("<div class=row>");
    } 
    if (currentCol == maxCol) 
    {
        @Html.Raw("</div>");
    }
    currentCol++;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Razor follows HTML and C#/VB syntax blocks, which is why breaking up tags does this. Two work-arounds:

1: Use `Html.Raw` (as you've done)

```
if (condition){
  @Html.Raw(@"<div class=""row"">")
}else{
  @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

2: Use the Special `<text>...</text>` tags.

```
if (condition){
  <text>
    <div class="row">
  </text>
}else{
  <text>
    </div>
  </text>
}
```

Remember that the `@` symbol, to the Razor parser, means you're making a transition from one language to the other (albeit HTML to code, or vice versa). So, since you're in an `if(...)` block and `Html.Raw` is actually outputting HTML, you need to use the `@`.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use:

```
if(condition){
 @:<div>
}

if(condition){
 @:</div>
}
```

Comment: Working Fine, On "CTRL + K + D" Due to Aliment Error