# Splitting <a> tags with if statements in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have several `<div>`s that comprise a menu whereby the user may select one of several options. Sometimes, however, the option needs to take the user to another page, i.e. sometimes it needs to have a link wrapped around it.

The following is a simplified version of my approach thus far:

```
@if (true)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = 1 })">
}

<div>
    A div with some stuff in it...
</div>

@if (true)
{
    </a>
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Parser Error Message:
The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406843/mvc-4-razor-if-splitting-div-tags) but it doesn't help me because the answers given use `Html.Raw()` and `<text>` which would preclude me from using the `@Url.Action()` in my link.

Is there a way to make this work or will I need to do something altogether different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you have like this:

```
@if (true)
{
    @Html.Raw("<a href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = 1 }) + "'>")
}

<div>
    A div with some stuff in it...
</div>

@if (true)
{
    @Html.Raw("</a>")
}
```

Although, this second option may be a bit cleaner, where you can set your div and content into a partial view:

```
@if (true)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = 1 })">
        @Html.Partial("PartialName")
    </a>
}else {
    @Html.Partial("PartialName")
}
```

And third option would be to write your own Html Helper.

Comment: I like the first option a lot, mainly because creating partials makes the HTML harder to read and edit (though it would be cleaner). This solves my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the thread [Razor view will not allow  to be split](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3944), this can be achieved without `@Html.Raw()` meaning your HTML doesn't have to end up in strings:

```
@if (1 == 1) { 
    @:<div> 
}
<div>some content</div>
@if (1 == 1) { 
    @:</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dotnet 6 you can also do the following and when using an HTML Helper, the best practice is to use PartialAsync.

```
@if (true)
{
    <div class="v-application">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Item", new { id = 1 })">

            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Partial/_LoginForm.cshtml")

        </a>
    </div>
}
else
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Partial/_LoginForm.cshtml")
}
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0